# How to show fragments in android tabbed menu (ViewPager)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I'm working on a tabbed (swipe) view for my app using google's guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs

I implemented everything successfully using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead, just because I only need 3 tabs. For that I used this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

The thing is that the views are changing according to an id (the view is created on the fly),
and my question is **how'd I change it to show any fragment (that was previously created) instead of the current behavior?**

As I said, I used the tutorials above.

Some code:

This is the `onCreateView` that sets the value of a `TextView` according to the id of the tab/fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
    View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
    return v;
}
```

Then there is the xml layout of `fragment_pager_list`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

<!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
the empty view or the list view.  -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!-- Here is the list. Since we are using a ListActivity, we
         have to call it "@android:id/list" so ListActivity will
         find it -->
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="No items."/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to save the state of tab ?

```
use this to save the state of tab
this.mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)
```

Let me know, this is the solution or not.

Comment: Can you please reply ?